# Generate random number without repetition

Tags: android

```
     bt.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){

            @Override
            public void onClick(View p1)
            {
                try{
                    List<Integer> dataList = new ArrayList<Integer>();
                    int start = 5;
                    int end = 15;
                    for (int i = start; i <= end; i++){
                        dataList.add(i);
                    }
                    Collections.shuffle(dataList);
                    int[] num = new int[dataList.size()];
                    for (int i = 0; i < dataList.size(); i++) {
                        num[i] = dataList.get(i);
                    }

                    for (int i = 0; i < num.length; i++) {


                    t.setText(num[i]);
                    }
                }catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }});
```

I want to show my random number on text view but it shown nothing or crash without catch Exception

What should I do?

What and where is my error?

Comment: Use `t.setText(String.valueOf(num[i]));` to show `int` in `TextView`

Comment: Where is your logcat???

Comment: Sir @ρяσѕρєяK  it only generate one number but i want 10 how can i do this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to use the diamond operator `<>`. You can only display one `String` at a time, so first make a `String` (and you don't need to copy to an array first). Something like,

```
try {
    List<Integer> dataList = new ArrayList<>(); // <-- <Integer> if you can't.
    int start = 5;
    int end = 15;
    for (int i = start; i <= end; i++) {
        dataList.add(i);
    }
    Collections.shuffle(dataList);
    t.setText(dataList.toString());
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: this seems like to be just shuffling meaning that there are chances that it will repeat a number before all numbers are exhausted

Comment: @kinsleykajiva Not true. If you take the number `5` to `15` and `shuffle` them, they will be in random order (and none will repeat).

Comment: i do get the motive but Shuffle function of Collection will only have the numbers in random order but will not gurantee that in a round or session that numbers will not be repeated, as the shuffle function does not keep track of which elements or number was repeated or not it will just re-position thus all. remember what the initial question demands